# How to gain access to private key of PKI certificate via Smart Card reader without PIN prompt?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, smartcard, pki

I need to gain access to private key of PKI certificate which is stored in a card. I have access to it via Smart Card reader. Whenever I try to use private key, at first time I always have to enter PIN number into PIN prompt.

Is it possible to enter PIN programmatically and use private key without PIN prompt? I need to create WCF service that will sign the input data using PKI certificate and take them back signed to user.

In that way I currently try to sign data using PKI certificate using C#:

```
var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(x509certificate2); // certificate fetched from store
var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(dataToSign);
var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);
```

PIN prompt always opens at the first `ComputeSignature` method call. How can I pass PIN to gain access to private key directly and avoid entering PIN manually via prompt?

Comment: From looking at the documentation looks like you just need to make sure `cmsSigner.Certificate` is set and ComputeSignature should be `ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, true)`, but I have never used this API before so I have no idea if I am even close to being right.

Comment: I've seen a question like this before, but the answer slips my mind :(

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I would appreciate if you could try to remind the answer.

Comment: The whole approach sounds suspicious. A PKI key on a smart card is person-related and the PIN is not a medium to make life harder for programmers, but to ensure, that exactly that person agrees to sign. Either you should have a separate non-person related key (it should be easy to find a smartcard with a key NOT needing a PIN), or you even don't require a smart card at all. But I find it hard to imagine a problem, where compromising the key on a existing card by storing its PIN on an arbitrarily insecure system is a sound solution.

Comment: you can achieve this using PKCS11 standard using https://pkcs11interop.net/

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to two situations:

1. the hardware CSP (crypto service provider) keeps to the Microsoft defined API and implements CspParameters correctly;
2. the hardware CSP itself generates a pop up for the PIN when a private key operation is required.

In the first case you should read [How to: Access Hardware Encryption Devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229931%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then try to pass [a `KeyPassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.keypassword(v=vs.110).aspx) to the CSP.

In the latter case it probably amounts to contacting the company that created the CSP and ask which options are available. Fortunately this option is usually not implemented anymore.

Comment: Warning: this rings true, but basically I just looked for it online. Downvote the hell out of it if it is incorrect :)